# How can I do the type deduction on parameterized template function

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts> void Print(Ts... args) { 
  (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}

template <typename T> void Add(T a, T b) { Print(a + b); } 

template <typename T> void Sub(T a, T b) { Print(a - b); } 

template <typename T> void Mul(T a, T b) { Print(a * b); } 

template <typename F, typename... Fns> void CallFuncs(F a, F b, Fns... fns) { 
  (fns(a, b), ...);
};

void FunctionInvokeTest() { CallFuncs(1, 2, Add<int>, Mul<int>); }

int main() { 
  FunctionInvokeTest();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to pass the template function as parameter shown as above.  The code works.  However I must put `<int>` after the function such as `Add<int>`.

If this is non-deductible context, then **is there another way to allow me write like this, where the `Add` and `Mul` are still template functions**?

```
CallFuncs(1,2, Add, Mul);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but you can turn functions into function objects:

```
struct Add {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T a, T b) {
        Print(a + b); } 
};

struct Mul {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T a, T b) {
        Print(a * b); } 
};

template<typename F, typename... Fns>
void CallFuncs(F a, F b, Fns... fns) {
    (fns(a, b), ...);
};

void FunctionInvokeTest() { 
    CallFuncs(1, 2, Add{}, Mul{});
}
```

`T` will be deduced from the type of `a` and `b`. In this example it will be `int`. To get `double`, you need `double` parameters:

```
CallFuncs(1., 2., Add{}, Mul{});
```

or explicit type specification:

```
CallFuncs<double>(1, 2, Add{}, Mul{});
```

---

This is very similar to "diamond" functors in the standard library (since C++14). For example, the [`std::plus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) declaration is

```
template<class T = void>
struct plus;
```

If `T` is `void` (e.g., in `std::plus<>{}`), `plus::operator()` deduces argument and return types. Typical [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_function.h#L229) looks like this (with some minor simplifications):

```
template<> struct plus<void> {
    template<typename Tp, typename Up>
    constexpr auto operator()(Tp&& t, Up&& u) const {
        return std::forward<Tp>(t) + std::forward<Up>(u);
    }
};
```

Comment: though note this will use `int` rather than `double` due to integer arguments

Comment: Wow.. Cool thanks man!  I spent 5 hours searching & reading books & try different ways coding and got the answer from you in 10 mins.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think its fine.  When we call std::max(...) we still need to specify the number is 1.0 rather than 1.

Comment: @WL_Law, I added an example from the standard library where this technique is used.

Answer (score 2):

If you can transform your template function into functor class, you might do:

```
struct Add {
    template <typename T>
    void operator ()(T a, T b) const { Print(a + b); } 
};

struct Sub
{
    template <typename T> void operator() (T a, T b) const  { Print(a - b); } 
};

struct Mul
{
    template <typename T> void operator() (T a, T b) const { Print(a * b); } 
};
```

Then you can do

```
void FunctionInvokeTest() { CallFuncs(1, 2, Add{}, Mul{}); }
```

Or to have more similar syntax:

```
constexpr Add add{};
constexpr Mul mul{};

void FunctionInvokeTest() { CallFuncs(1, 2, add, mul); }
```

If you cannot change your function, wrapping them in lambda might help:

```
void FunctionInvokeTest() { CallFuncs(1, 2,
                                      [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { Add(lhs, rhs); },
                                      [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { Mul(lhs, rhs); }); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Workaround by moving function arguments into template

```
template <typename F>
using BinaryOp = void(F, F); // function type

// fns is now a pack of function objects instead of types
template <typename F, BinaryOp<F>... fns>
void CallFuncs(F a, F b) { 
  (fns(a, b), ...);
};

void FunctionInvokeTest() {
    // the functions are now passed as template arguments alongside the desired numeric type
    CallFuncs<float, Add, Mul>(1, 2); 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/DutpHk